# primefaces does not have the property 'handleDateSelect'

Tags: calendar, primefaces

I just started using PrimeFaces and cannot figure what is wrong with my code.  It is exactly the same as the show case sample with the exception of the bean names.  I looked at this site for answers without success.

PrimeFaces:

```
<p:calendar value="#{securityForecastReturnBean.date}"
                    mode="inline" onSelectUpdate="inputsGrowl"
                    selectListener="#{securityForecastReturnBean.handleDateSelect}"
                    required="true" />
```

Java Bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@ManagedBean
public class SecurityForecastReturnBean {
public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected",
                        format.format(event.getDate())));
    }
```

}

It should be really straightforward yet it is saying that my bean does not have this property??

Here is the exact error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /security_page.xhtml: The class 'com.ls.forecast.webui.beans.SecurityForecastReturnBean' does not have the property 'handleDateSelect'.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
```

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  It had to do with using the wrong namespace.  I had to use http://primefaces.org/ui instead of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be an error in the documentation:

From the Primefaces Guide 2.2:

> Ajax Selection
>   Calendar supports instant ajax selection which means whenever a date is selected a server side
>   selectListener can be invoked with an org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent instance as a
>   parameter. Optional onSelectUpdate option allows updating other component(s) on page.

```
   <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}" onSelectUpdate="messages"
       selectListener="#{calendarBean.handleDateSelect}" />
         <p:messages id="messages" />

    public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
        Date date = event.getDate();
        //Add facesmessage
    }
```

Programatically it seems to expect a property on the managed bean.  You can try changing it to this and see if it makes a difference `#{calendarBean.handleDateSelect()}`.  Are you absolutely sure that you are not referencing `handleDateSelect` elsewhere in the markup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried adding the parenthesis such as `securityForecastReturnBean.handleDateSelect()` without luck: same error message.   I am also sure that I am not referencing handleDateSelect method on any other mark up since it is the only place where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The source code example given in the PrimeFaces Showcase is wrong.  The method should not be taking org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent, it should be taking org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent.  A quick change to the source code example now looks like this:

```
public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {  
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");  
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected", format.format(event.getDate())));  
}
```